# R merge data frame columns to a new column as a vector

Tags: r

I need to merge all columns of data frame into a new column that will contain a vector(list) of the values in other columns. Something like this

```
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c(3,3,5)
b = c(1,1,1)
df = data.frame(n, s, b)

  n s b
1 2 3 1
2 3 3 1
3 5 5 1
```

And I want to run a command that gives me something like this:

```
  n s b   v
1 2 3 1 [2,3,1]
2 3 3 1 [3,3,1]
3 5 5 1 [5,5,1]
```

Basically, something like this

```
t(as.numeric(df[1,1:3]))
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    1
```

Gets me what I want for one row, but I can't figure out how do add it for all rows. I've tried various `apply` functions without much success.

Thanks.

Comment: How about `df$v <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ', '))`

Comment: Thanks. I tried it with paste previously, but it creates a string and not a vector/list of numbers. And I need the numerics.

Comment: Use `list` instead of `paste` then?

Comment: This could do `df$v <- as.list(as.data.frame(t(df)))`

Comment: Also `df$v <- split(as.matrix(df),rownames(df))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little known feature that you can append matrices to dataframes:

```
> df[4] <- data.matrix(df)
> df
  n s b V4.n V4.s V4.b
1 2 3 1    2    3    1
2 3 3 1    3    3    1
3 5 5 1    5    5    1
> df[4]
  V4.n V4.s V4.b
1    2    3    1
2    3    3    1
3    5    5    1
> df[4,1]    # note that the 4th "column" actually a list needs to be addresses as a whole:
[1] NA   # the 
> df[4][ 1, ]
     n s b
[1,] 2 3 1
```

If you want to extract individual elements, you need to first extract with "[[":

```
> df[[4]][ , 1 ]
[1] 2 3 5
```

Comment: It sometimes shows up in older code. The `print`-output can be a bit confusing, since the matrix columns are not offered separately. I get the sense most coders don't use it now but I think it is more "stable" as a coding strategy than would be encoding these as a list of lists.